# Button to Change Font Size globally

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, expo

I'm working with a global style sheet and settings js files. I would like the app users to be able to increase and decrease the global font size from the settings page to their liking.

Below is code from `sharedStyles.js` file

```js
//For Global Styling
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View
} from 'react-native'

//importing settings
import settings from '../screen_view/settings_page';


const sharedStyles = StyleSheet.create({

  description: {

    textAlign: 'center',

    //increase font size
    fontSize: settings.count,

    padding: 6,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: "black",
    backgroundColor: "lightcyan",


  }
})

export default sharedStyles;
```

Below is code from settings.js file

```js
import React, {
  useState
} from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  Button,
  StyleSheet
} from "react-native";

//Import Shared Styles
import sharedStyles from '../shared/sharedStyles';

const FontSize = () => {

  const [count, setCount] = useState(10);

  return (


    <
    View >

    <
    Text style = {
      sharedStyles.description.fontSize
    } > FONT SIZE < /Text>


    <
    Button title = "Increase Font Size"
    onPress = {
      () => {
        setCount(sharedStyles.description.fontSize.count + 5);
      }
    }
    />

    <
    /View>
  );
};

export default FontSize;
```

In the settings page, I have a button to increase the global font-size but it does not work, how do I make this work, please?

I want to have 2 buttons to increase and decrease the global font size on the settings page.